# UnboundLocalError with nested function scopes

Tags: python, function

I have code like this (simplified):

```
def outer():
    ctr = 0

    def inner():
        ctr += 1

    inner()
```

But `ctr` causes an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "foo.py", line 9, in <module>
    outer()
  File "foo.py", line 7, in outer
    inner()
  File "foo.py", line 5, in inner
    ctr += 1
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'ctr' referenced before assignment
```

How can I fix this? I thought nested scopes would have allowed me to do this. I've tried with 'global', but it still doesn't work.

Comment: also look to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2516652/scoping-problem-in-recursive-closure

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python overwriting variables in nested functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7935966/python-overwriting-variables-in-nested-functions)

Answer (score 102, accepted):

If you're using Python 3, you can use the `nonlocal` statement to enable rebinding of a nonlocal name:

```
def outer():
    ctr = 0

    def inner():
        nonlocal ctr
        ctr += 1

    inner()
```

If you're using Python 2, which doesn't have `nonlocal`, you need to perform your incrementing without barename rebinding (by keeping the counter as an item or attribute of some barename, **not** as a barename itself).  For example:

```
...
ctr = [0]

def inner():
    ctr[0] += 1
...
```

and of course use `ctr[0]` wherever you're using bare `ctr` now elsewhere.

Comment: This seems almost too like a 'hack'. I'll use it, but it seems like a limitation of Python 2.x. Guess I'll be using 3.x soon though.

Comment: Alex - thanks - this scoping issue was making function composition messy in 2.x

Comment: Thanks ; I was going nuts trying to understand why I got an `UnboundLocalError` when I assigned the variable. Now that I see it, it actually makes sense. In C++, we have kind of the same concept with lambdas, except you declare the capturing before declaring the arguments, rather than in the body of the lambda.

Answer (score 53):

### The Explanation

Whenever a value is assigned to a variable inside a function, python considers that variable a *local variable* of that function. (It doesn't even matter if the assignment is executed or not - as long as an assignment *exists* in a function, the variable being assigned to will be considered a local variable of that function.) Since the statement `ctr += 1` includes an assignment to `ctr`, python thinks that `ctr` is local to the `inner` function. Consequently, it never even tries to look at the value of the `ctr` variable that's been defined in `outer`. What python sees is essentially this:

```
def inner():
    ctr = ctr + 1
```

And I think we can all agree that this code would cause an error, since `ctr` is being accessed before it has been defined.

(See also [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/executionmodel.html#naming-and-binding) or [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49538724/1222951) for more details about how python decides the scope of a variable.)

### The Solution (in python 3)

Python 3 has introduced the [`nonlocal` statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#grammar-token-nonlocal_stmt), which works much like the `global` statement, but lets us access variables of the surrounding function (rather than global variables). Simply add `nonlocal ctr` at the top of the `inner`function and the problem will go away:

```
def outer():
    ctr = 0

    def inner():
        nonlocal ctr
        ctr += 1

    inner()
```

### The Workaround (in python 2)

Since the `nonlocal` statement doesn't exist in python 2, we have to be crafty. There are two easy workarounds:

- **Removing all assignments to `ctr`**

  Since python only considers `ctr` a local variable because there's an assignment to that variable, the problem will go away if we remove all assignments to the name `ctr`. But how can we change the value of the variable without assigning to it? Easy: We wrap the variable in a mutable object, like a list. Then we can modify that list without ever assigning a value to the name `ctr`:

  ```
  def outer():
      ctr = [0]

      def inner():
          ctr[0] += 1

      inner()
  ```
- **Passing `ctr` as an argument to `inner`**

  ```
  def outer():
      ctr = 0

      def inner(ctr):
          ctr += 1
          return ctr

      ctr = inner(ctr)
  ```

Comment: I always appreciate answers that explain a specific behavior instead of just putting a piece of code. +1

Comment: The local scoping behaviour of inner functions you explained also occurs when an outer variable is used in a conditional statement in an inner function, not just during variable assignments.

Comment: @SeanFrancisN.Ballais Not true. The only thing that makes a variable local is a [name binding operation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/executionmodel.html#binding-of-names), and a conditional isn't one of them.

Comment: Passing as an argument doesn’t work if it’s a string, though‽

Answer (score -2):

How about declaring `ctr` outside of `outer` (i.e. in the global scope), or any other class/function? This will make the variable accessible and writable.

Comment: Yes, but it's a bit messy having global variables just for one or two functions - better to keep them in local scopes so you know why you put them there in the first place.