# About function inside another function in Python

Tags: python, function, scope, behavior

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Python variable scope question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/370357/python-variable-scope-question)
>   [Python nested function scopes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2609518/python-nested-function-scopes)

I'm confused about the following piece of code

```
def func():
    a=10
    def func2():
        print a
        a=20
    func2()
    print a

func()
```

In python 2.7, when running the above code, python will give an error, `UnboundLocalError`, complaining in `func2`, when `print a`, 'a' is referenced before assignment

However, if I comment `a=20` in `func2`, everything goes well. Python will print two lines of 10; i.e, the following code is correct.

```
def func():
    a=10
    def func2():
        print a

    func2()
    print a

func()
```

Why? Since in other languages, like c/c++

```
{
    a=10
    {
        cout<<a<<endl //will give 10
        a=20          //here is another a
        cout<<a<<endl //here will give 20
    }
}
```

local and outer variables can be distinguished very clearly.

Comment: in python, everything you assign to is assumed to be local.

Comment: My guees would be that the scope of func2 is independent of the scope of func. You basically just defining a function func2 which is just visible in the scope of func. That doesn implicies that func2 sees the local variables in func.

Comment: sorry, I didn't find these duplicates. should I delete my questions?

Answer (score 1):

By adding the line `a=20`, Python analyzes the code and sees that `a` is also used as a local variable name. In that case you are trying to print the value of a variable that has not yet been defined (in `func2`).

Without that line, Python will use the value of `a` from the scope of `func` (which is still valid inside `func2`). You are correct that this is different from your example in C/C++.