# why i face problem when i'm going to pass a dynamic function in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dynamic-code

I'm going to pass a function dynamically to another class as shown below

```
    class simulator(object):
        def __init__(self, fn_):

            print(self.test(fn_))


        def test(self, fn):
            return  fn(self, 20)


    class t(object):

        s = 'def get_fitness(x, y):\n return x+y'

        exec(s)

        def fnGetFitness(self,genes):
            return get_fitness(genes, 10)

        simulator(fnGetFitness)



    t()
```

but i face error below:

```
    File "N:/Job/GA/mine/dyn.py", line 25, in fnGetFitness
          return get_fitness(genes, 10)

    NameError: name 'get_fitness' is not defined
```

i guess its something related to scopes but i can't handle it
anyone on this?

EDIT :

this is a simpler code, showing the problem :

```
    class t(object):
        def __init__(self):
            exec('def get_fitness(x, y):\n return x+y')
            print(get_fitness(2,3))
    t()
```

Comment: I only see `get_fitness` inside of the string `s` but never as function?

Comment: What your trying to achieve by doing this ?

Comment: @mark he runs `exec` on it

Comment: i'm trying to read a function from a file and pass it to a class to call. @LavanyaPant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

nothing to do with `exec`. What you're doing is equivalent (with safety removed) to:

```
class t(object):
    def get_fitness(x,y):
        return x+y
```

but your method definition is at class level, but not on the `simulator` class.

`simulator(fnGetFitness)` calls `fnGetFitness` out of `t` class context, so it doesn't know your new function.

That cannot work (also `get_fitness` should be decorated as `@staticmethod` because it doesn't have a `self` parameter)

What works is to define dynamically (or not) the function at *global* level so class can call it

```
s = 'def get_fitness(x, y):\n return x+y'
exec(s)

class t(object):
    def fnGetFitness(self,genes):
        return get_fitness(genes, 10)

    simulator(fnGetFitness)

t()
```

that fixed it, but honestly I'm puzzled about the purpose (already took me a while to figure out how to make something run from your code)

EDIT: a simpler and somehow different (and `exec` related) code has been posted in comments:

```
class t(object):
    def __init__(self):
        exec('def get_fitness(x, y):\n return x+y')
        print(get_fitness(2,3))
t()
```

this raises `NameError: name 'get_fitness' is not defined`

*now* this has to do with `exec`. When `__init__` is parsed, `get_fitness` isn't known because the parser didn't see it as a local variable, even if at the time of execution, it is set in `locals()` dictionary by `exec` (related: [why is 'ord' seen as an unassigned variable here?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49538724/why-is-ord-seen-as-an-unassigned-variable-here)).

A workaround is to fetch the function in the local variables like this:

```
class t(object):
    def __init__(self):
        exec('def get_fitness(x, y):\n return x+y')
        print(locals()["get_fitness"](2,3))

t()
```

this works & prints `5`.

Comment: In fact I want to read a function from a file or let user write their code in a TextCtrl then my app is possible to run the code. I can't find a way to define passed-code as a global function :(

Comment: it's difficult to see the relations and what the use function can do in the object context with just `x+y`. With `x+y`, you can insert it anywhere, it'll work. If you want to use helper methods, I suggest that you use a different method, like child classes.

Comment: here is the simplified version of my problem:   
class t(object):
    def __init__(self):
        exec('def get_fitness(x, y):\n return x+y') 
        print(get_fitness(2,3))

t()

Comment: the problem in this (simpler) code in comment, is that `get_fitness` isn't dynamically defined. `get_fitness` doesn't exist when the function is parsed. `exec` something doesn't work to define dynamically at this level

Comment: see my edit for explanation & solution :) maybe you should edit your question to put this snippet, and I'll edit my answer.