# Global variables in embedded functions

Tags: python, python-3.x, global-variables

I have the following snippet:

```
def test ():
  num_sum = 0
  def inner_test ():
    global num_sum
    num_sum += 1
  inner_test()
return num_sum
```

When I run test() I get:

> NameError: name 'num_sum' is not defined

I was expecting that the inner function would change the value of the `num_sum` variable defined in the outer function. Basically, I need a global variable to increment in an inner function which I may call recursively.

I noticed that this pattern works well with collections (lists, dictionaries) even if I don't define the variable as global (but pass it as a parameter to the inner function).

However, with scalar values like `int` this pattern seems to break. Neither defining the variable as global (as is here) nor passing it as a parameter to the inner function works as intended. Basically, the scalar variable stays unchanged. What do I need to do to get the desired behaviour with such scalar values?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UnboundLocalError with nested function scopes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2609518/unboundlocalerror-with-nested-function-scopes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need [`nonlocal`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#nonlocal) instead of `global`. your `num_sum` is not a global variable (will not be found in `globals()`). `nonlocal` will instruct python not to search for it in the global namespace, but in the nearest namespace. the order is [LEGB: Local, Enclosed, Global, Built-in](https://sebastianraschka.com/Articles/2014_python_scope_and_namespaces.html).