# Python scope problems only when _assigning_ to a variable

Tags: python

So I'm having a very strange error right now. I found where it happens, and here's the simplest code that can reproduce it.

```
def cause_an_error():
    some_var = False
    def some_nested_func():
        print some_var
        #some_var = True
    some_nested_func()

>>> cause_an_error()
False
```

If you run it as-is, it prints "False". But if you uncomment that line, it gives an error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#224>", line 1, in <module>
    cause_an_error()
  File "<pyshell#223>", line 6, in cause_an_error
    some_nested_func()
  File "<pyshell#223>", line 4, in some_nested_func
    print some_var
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'some_var' referenced before assignment
```

Notice the error occurs on the line that *worked just fine before*.

Any ideas what causes this and how I can fix this? I'm using Python 2.6.1.

Comment: very similar to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2516652/scoping-problem-in-recursive-closure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inner function, `some_nest_func`, has its own scope, and the fact that you are assigning to `some_var` somewhere within that scope makes `some_var` local to that scope. This has the effect of hiding the `some_var` assigned in the outer function. They are two different variables.

The upshot of all this is that you are printing `some_nest_func`'s version of `some_var` before you assign to it.

If you need to manipulate some variable both in and outside the inner function, there isn't a clean way to it, AFAIK. A simple work-around is to replace the variable with a single-element array and manipulate that isn't (don't assign to the array variable, of course).

Comment: That makes sense to me. But shouldn't the non-local variable only be shadowed *after* the assignment?

Comment: The shadowing happens at compile time. If Python finds an assignment anywhere within the scope, all references become local.

Comment: I've amended my answer. Also see Ignacio's answer for Python 3.0.

Answer (score 1):

This can't be fixed in 2.x without refactoring the code. 3.x adds [`nonlocal`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-nonlocal-statement) to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by changing a value of a referenced (read mutable) variable such as dict,  although ugly, this solution (transcribed from [an answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3190783/484127)) should work:

```
def avoid_an_error():
    D = {"some_var": False}
    def some_nested_func():
        D["some_var"] = True
        print D["some_var"]
    some_nested_func()

>>> avoid_an_error()
True
```