# python counter with closure

Tags: python, closures

I'm trying to build a counter in python with the property of closure. The code in the following works:

```
def generate_counter():
    CNT = [0]
    def add_one():
        CNT[0] = CNT[0] + 1
        return CNT[0]
    return add_one
```

However when I change the list CNT to a var, it did not work:

```
def generate_counter1():
    x = 0
    def add_one():
        x = x + 1
        return x
    return add_one
```

when I print the closure property of an instance, I found the `__closure__` of the second case is none:

```
>>> ct1 = generate_counter()
>>> ct2 = generate_counter1()
>>> print(ct1.__closure__[0])
<cell at 0xb723765c: list object at 0xb724370c>
>>> print(ct2.__closure__)
None
```

Just wondering why the index in outer function has to be a list?

---

Thanks for the answers! Found the docs which clearly explained this problem
https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#why-am-i-getting-an-unboundlocalerror-when-the-variable-has-a-value

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4851463/python-closure-write-to-variable-in-parent-scope

Answer (score 19):

Python determines the scope of a name by looking at name binding behaviour; assignment is one such behaviour (function parameters, importing, the target in `for target ...` or `while .. as target` are other examples). A name you bind to in a function is considered *local*. See the [*Naming and Binding* section](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/executionmodel.html#naming-and-binding) of the reference documentation.

So the name `x` in your second example is a *local* variable, because you assigned directly to it:

```
x = x + 1
```

In fact, because you never gave that `x` a local value, you'll get an exception when you try to use that function; the local name is *unbound* when you try to read it:

```
>>> generate_counter1()()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in add_one
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'x' referenced before assignment
```

In your first example no such binding takes place; you are instead altering the *contents* of `CNT`, what that name references is not altered.

If you are using Python 3, you can override the decision to make a name local, by using a [`nonlocal` statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-nonlocal-statement):

```
def generate_counter2():
    x = 0
    def add_one():
        nonlocal x
        x = x + 1
        return x
    return add_one
```

By making `x` non-local, Python finds it in the parent context and creates a closure for it again.

```
>>> def generate_counter2():
...     x = 0
...     def add_one():
...         nonlocal x
...         x = x + 1
...         return x
...     return add_one
...
>>> generate_counter2().__closure__
(<cell at 0x1078c62e8: int object at 0x1072c8070>,)
```

`nonlocal` is new in Python 3; in Python 2 you are limited to tricks like using a mutable list object to evade the binding rule. Another trick would be to assign the counter to an attribute of the nested function; again, this avoids binding a name in the current scope:

```
def generate_counter3():
    def add_one():
        add_one.x += 1
        return add_one.x
    add_one.x = 0
    return add_one
```

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't *have* to be a list, it just has to be an mutable object which you *mutate*, not reassign.

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#what-are-the-rules-for-local-and-global-variables-in-python):

> If a variable is assigned a value anywhere within the function’s body, it’s assumed to be a local unless explicitly declared as global.

Thus, in your second example, `x` is considered local (to the inner function), and, after your first assignment, you're shadowing the outer 'x'.

On the other hand, in the first example (since you don't assign a value to `CNT`) it operates on the `CNT` defined in the outer function.

Comment: "it just has to be an immutable object" I think you mean mutable?

Comment: @roganjosh Indeed I did! thanks for the correction :)