# Python2 referenced before assignment?

Tags: python-2.7, scope, instance-variables

This gives me a referenced before assignment error for `p1` but not for `count`?

```
class Bagadclass:
    def __init__(self):
        print "i n s t a n t i a t e d"
        pass

    def getRegion(self):
        count = [0]
        p1 = [0 , 0]
        p2 = [0 , 0]

        def on_click(x,y,button,pressed):
            count[0] += 1

            if count[0] > 5:
                self.Image = pyautogui.screenshot(region=p1+p2)
                listener.stop()
                pass

            if count[0] == 2:
                p1 = list(pyautogui.position())
                pass

            if count[0] == 4:
                print p1
                p2 = (pyautogui.position()[0] - p1[0] , pyautogui.position()[1] - p1[1])
                pass

            print count , x , y , button , pressed
            pass

        with Listener(on_click=on_click) as listener:
            listener.join()
        pass
```

Can anyone explain why? I think this is about the listener object or something but if it worked for `count` i think it should also work for the other variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function `on_click()` is a closure, it has access to the variables `count`, `p1`, and `p2`, defined in the enclosing scope, `getRegion()`. These variables, (`count`, `p1`, `p2`) are known as *free variables**, "If a variable is used in a code block **but not defined there**, it is a free variable" [<sup>Link 1</sup>](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/executionmodel.html).

*Actually, in your example, only `count` is a free variable; `p1` and `p2` are **not** free variables, as you have defined them in the local scope of `on_click()`:

```
...

if count[0] == 2:
    p1 = list(pyautogui.position()) # <-- here
    pass

if count[0] == 4:
    print p1
    p2 = (pyautogui.position()[0] - p1[0] , pyautogui.position()[1] - p1[1]) # <-- and here

...
```

And so are no longer free variables, they are now *local variables*. In each *block*, a name is either a *local variable*, a *global variable* or a *free variable*. A name does not transform from a free variable to a local variable after the assignment statement, instead, if an assignment statement appears anywhere within a block, the name is now a local variable. If you try to access a local variable that has not yet been bound (i.e. code execution has not yet reached the assignment statement of the local variable), you will get an `UnboundLocalError` exception.

From [Execution model — Python 2.7.15 documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/executionmodel.html):

> If a name binding operation occurs anywhere within a code block, all uses of the name within the block are treated as references to the current block. This can lead to errors when a name is used within a block before it is bound. This rule is subtle. Python lacks declarations and allows name binding operations to occur anywhere within a code block. The local variables of a code block can be determined by scanning the entire text of the block for name binding operations.

In essence, this basically means you can 'access' free variables (including modify/mutate them) but you can't 'write'/rebind them, Python will interpret this as defining an entirely new local variable. In Python 3, you can resolve this by using the [`nonlocal`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#nonlocal) keyword, otherwise a [common practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3190706/nonlocal-keyword-in-python-2-x) is to wrap your data in another structure (e.g. dictionary or list) and then modify the structure to alter your data instead; this way, you are not attempting to rebind the free variable, merely modifying the object it refers to.

This is in fact what has already been done for the `count` variable, the actual count value is stored in a single element list and when `on_click()` needs to increment the count, it increments the first element of the `count` list (`count[0]+=1`), instead of trying to rebind it (something like `count+=1` would not work).

---

Example of how you might revise your code (`# !` indicates changes):

```
...

    def getRegion(self):
        count = [0]
        p = [[0, 0], [0, 0]]  # [p1, p2]  # !
        def on_click(x,y,button,pressed):
            count[0] += 1
            if count[0] > 5:
                self.Image = pyautogui.screenshot(region=p[0]+p[1])  # !

...

            if count[0] == 2:
                p[0] = list(pyautogui.position())  # !

...

            if count[0] == 4:
                print p[0] # !
                p[1] = (pyautogui.position()[0] - p[0][0],
                        pyautogui.position()[1] - p[0][1])  # !

...
```

---

**Links:**

1. [Execution model — Python 2.7.15 documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/executionmodel.html)
2. [Why am I getting an UnboundLocalError when the variable has a value? — Python 2.7.15 documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/faq/programming.html#why-am-i-getting-an-unboundlocalerror-when-the-variable-has-a-value)
3. [How to define free-variable in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12919278/8944057)
4. [python counter with closure](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38693236/8944057)