# How to count cumulative calls of the Fibonacci function?

Tags: python, recursion

I tried :

```
def fibonnaci(n):
        total_call = 0
        if n ==0 or n == 1:
            return 1
        else:
            if n== 2 or n == 1:
                total_call +=0
            else:
                total_call +=2

            return fibonnaci(n - 1) + fibonnaci(n - 2), total_call


n = 8
print(fibonnaci(n))
```

but I got a error:

```
TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "int") to tuple
```

How to display the number of calls for fibonnaci?

Comment: What the of value is `fibonacci` supposed to return?

Comment: On the else branch n== 2 or n == 1 is actually n == 2 as n == 1 always False on that branch.

Comment: @Scott Hunter fibonnaci(3) total_call = 5, for example

Comment: @oszkar I did not understand!

Comment: Check my edited post, I posted an answer using function attributes and using your approach @LaurindaSouza

Comment: @LaurindaSouza on the outer `else` branch from `if n== 2 or n == 1:` you can remove the ` or n == 1` part as on that branch `n != 1` (because of the preceding `if n == 0 or n == 1:`).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is "obvious", if you bother to trace the values you're using:

```
return fibonnaci(n - 1) + fibonnaci(n - 2), total_call
```

When `n` is 3, this tries to "add" fibonnaci(2), a tuple, and fibonnaci(1), the integer `1`.  This is not a legal operation.  You need to regularize your return values.  You can't magically return the value alone (not the count) when that's what you want; you have to explicitly program the difference: dismember the tuple and add the component values.

Start with your base case being

```
return 1, 0
```

Your recursion case needs to add the components.  Implementation is left s an exercise for the student.

Comment: I did not understand how to fix it... Could you show it?

Comment: This is not a coding service.  If you have a *specific* question, please edit your post; "I did not understand" is not a specification.  Exactly what do you not understand?

Answer (score 1):

```
def fib(n):

    if n <= 1:
        return n, 1
    fib_one = fib(n - 1)
    fib_two = fib(n - 2)
    #Return the result and the number of function calls (+ 1 for the current call)
    return fib_one[0] + fib_two[0], fib_one[1] + fib_two[1] + 1




if __name__ == '__main__':
    number_of_function_calls = fib(4)[1]
```

Fib(4) should return 9, which it does

```
                      fib(4)  
              fib(3)            fib(2)
          fib(2)   fib(1)   fib(1)     fib(0)
      fib(1)  fib(0)
```

Comment: I did not understand -> fib.number_of_function_calls  what is it? Why using dot notation?

Comment: @LaurindaSouza this is known as a function attribute. It allows you to keep state throughout all recursive calls. This way you can just incremnet a counter and its value will remain throghout all recursive calls. The second approach may also work for you.

Comment: fib(4) calls 7 times not 8 times... I reckon that something is wrong... Is it not? (I calculate it manually)

Comment: @LaurindaSouza Fib(4) has 9 function calls. See my updated solution. I show the recursive tree.The first solution I had up using function attributes was returning 8 instead of 9, so I removed it.

Answer (score 1):

In your `return` statement the result of both `fibonnaci(n - 1)` and `fibonnaci(n - 2)` could be a tuple (`argument > 1`), or a single integer (`argument <= 1`) thus `+` means concatenation when the first one is a tuple. But when `n == 3` in `return fibonacci(n - 1) + fibonacci(n - 2), total_call`  `fibonacci(2)`  is a tuple (`(2, total_call)`), while `fibonacci(1)` is an integer (`1`). So you want to concatenate a tuple with with an integer, which is impossible.

Answer (score 1):

**Using Decorators**

1. **Using Function Attributes**

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44968004/python-decorators-count-function-call)

*Code*

```
def call_counter(func):
    " Does the call count for any function "
    def helper(x):
        helper.calls += 1
        return func(x)
    helper.calls = 0
    return helper

@call_counter
def fib(n):
  if n ==0 or n == 1:
    return 1
  return fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2)
```

*Usage*

```
fib(5)
print(fib.calls)

fib(10)

print(fib.calls)  # Keeps running total so will be from previous 
                  # fib(5) plus current fib(10)

# To reset counter
fib.calls = 0
```

2. Using Class

[Reference](https://gist.github.com/fmder/1333765)

*Code*

```
class countCalls(object):
    """Decorator that keeps track of the number of times a function is called.
    ::

        >>> @countCalls
        ... def foo():
        ...     return "spam"
        ... 
        >>> for _ in range(10)
        ...     foo()
        ... 
        >>> foo.count()
        10
        >>> countCalls.counts()
        {'foo': 10}

    Found in the Pythod Decorator Library from http://wiki.python.org/moin web site.
    """

    instances = {}

    def __init__(self, func):
        self.func = func
        self.numcalls = 0
        countCalls.instances[func] = self

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.numcalls += 1
        return self.func(*args, **kwargs)

    def count(self):
        "Return the number of times this function was called."
        return countCalls.instances[self.func].numcalls

    @staticmethod
    def counts():
        "Return a dict of {function: # of calls} for all registered functions."
        return dict([(func.__name__, countCalls.instances[func].numcalls) for func in countCalls.instances])


@countCalls
def fib(n):
  if n ==0 or n == 1:
    return 1
  return fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2)
```

*Example*

```
print(fib(3))      # Output 3
print(fib.count()) # Output 5
```

*Advantage*

Allows obtaining counts of all registered functions (i.e. registered by using decorator)

```
@countCalls
def f(n):
  pass  # dummy function

@countCalls
def g(n):
  pass  # dummy function

for i in range(5):
  f(i)

for i in range(10):
  g(i)

print(countCalls.counts())

# Outputs: {'f': 5, 'g': 10}
```

Comment: If you are going to use a decorator, dont use an ugly function-attribute hack: `helper.calls += 1`, use *the closure*.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga--good suggestion as I must have been [laid astry by](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44968004/python-decorators-count-function-call).  However, in the closure method, I can't seem to reset the counter.

Comment: @DarrylG   I am confused:   closure method?

Comment: @LaurindaSouza--I update my post with an example using closures.

Comment: @LaurindaSouza-updated my answer with an additional decorator different method (i.e. using a Class).  [Counter with closure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38693236/python-counter-with-closure) shows how to use closure for a counter. However, I found this method problematic for counting function calls.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga--tried using a closure but found it problematic.  Could you provide further feedback on how you would use a closure?  Updated my answer with an additional decorator method (i.e. using a Class).

Answer (score 0):

Here's another answer using a decorator. The advantage of using a decorator is that the base function `fib` does not need to change. That means the `total_count` code and multiple return values can be discarded from your original attempt -

```
@counter(model = fib_result)
def fib(n = 0):
  if n < 2:
    return n
  else:
    return fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2)
```

Our decorator `counter` accepts a `model` so we can respond to the behavior of the decorated function. Our decorated `fib` will return a `fib_result` such as `{ result: ?, count: ? }`. That means we also need to handle `fib(?) + fib(?)` which is why we also defined `__add__` -

```py
class fib_result:
  def __init__(self, result, count = 0):
    if isinstance(result, fib_result):
      self.result = result.result
      self.count = result.count + count
    else:
      self.result = result
      self.count = count
  def __add__(a, b):
    return fib_result(a.result + b.result, a.count + b.count)
```

As you can see, this `fib_result` is specific to counting `fib` calls. A different model may be required for counting other recursive functions that return other types of results.

All that's left now is to define our generic `counter` decorator. Our decorator takes arguments and returns a new decorator, `lambda f: ...`, which simply captures the passed arguments, `lambda *args: ...`, and constructs a new `model` with the result of `f(*args)` and a base count of `1` -

```py
def counter(model = tuple):
  return lambda f: lambda *args: model(f(*args), 1)
```

Here's how the complete program works -

```py
r = fib(4)
print(f"answer: {r.result}, recurs: {r.count}")
# answer: 3, recurs: 9

r = fib(10)
print(f"answer: {r.result}, recurs: {r.count}")
# answer: 55, recurs: 177
```