# How to make variable accessible inside another function

Tags: python, scope, reference

Consider this example:

```
def func1():
    val = 1
    res = [1]
    def fun2():
        print(res)
        print(val)
        val = 2 
    fun2()
    print(val)

func1()
```

It raises the following exception:

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'val' referenced before assignment
```

List `res` can be accessed by `fun2`, but `val` cannot. I know `list` is mutable and `int` is not, but is there a way to make `val` accessible by `fun2` as well? In a class, I could easily achieve that with `self.val`, but is there a way to do it inside a function?

Comment: It's because the `val = 2` makes a new (local to fun2) variable called `val`. Remove that line and it works.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4851463/in-python-2-how-do-i-write-to-variable-in-the-parent-scope

Comment: Or if this is python 3, you can add `nonlocal val` to the top of `fun2` definition.

Comment: Mutability is irrelevant. The issue is you've assigned to `val` so it defaults to local

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`nonlocal` statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#nonlocal) to make a variable defined in an enclosing function accesible inside the inner function, like so:

```
def func1():
    val = 1
    res = [1]
    def fun2():
        nonlocal val
        print(res)
        print(val)
        val = 2 
    fun2()
    print(val)

func1()
```

See also: [earlier SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1261875/python-nonlocal-statement).

Comment: Should note it's only in Python 3, since OP didn't say which version they're using.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in the following way:

```
def func1():
    val = 1
    res = [1]
    def fun2(val=val, res=res):
        print(res)
        print(val)
        val = 2 
        return val
    val = fun2()
    print(val)
```

Output is then

```
>>> func1()
[1]
1
2
```