# Python and closed variables

Tags: python, closures, python-2.x

Have a look at this code:

```
def closure():
    value = False

    def method_1():
        value = True

    def method_2():
        print 'value is:', value

    method_1()
    method_2()

closure()
```

I would expect it to print 'Value is: True' but it doesn't. Why is this and what is the solution?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This happens because `method_1` gets its own local scope where it can declare variables. Python sees `value = True` and thinks you're creating a new variable named `value`, local to `method_1`.

The reason Python does this is to avoid polluting the outer scope's locals with variables from an inner function. (You wouldn't want assignments in regular, module-level functions to result in global variables being created!)

If you don't assign to `value`, then Python searches the outer scopes looking for the variable (so *reading* the variable works as expected, as demonstrated by your `method_2`).

One way to get around this is by using a mutable object instead of assigment:

```
result = { 'value': False }

def method_1():
    result['value'] = True
```

In Python 3, the [`nonlocal` statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1261875/python-nonlocal-statement) (see also [docs](http://docs.python.org/release/3.0.1/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-nonlocal-statement)) was added for exactly this scenario:

```
def method_1():
    nonlocal value
    value = True    # Works as expected -- assigns to `value` from outer scope
```

Answer (score 2):

In `method_1`, Python assumes (quite sensibly!) that `value` is a local variable. Whenever you assign to a variable name inside a function, it is assumed that that variable name is a new local variable. If you want it to be global, then you have to declare it as `global`, and if you want it to be "nonlocal", in Python 3, you can declare it `nonlocal`, but in Python 2, you have to do something uglier: store the value in a container. That avoids having to reassign the variable name, and so avoids the scoping ambiguity.

```
def method_1_global():
    global value
    value = True

def method_1_nonlocal_P3():
    nonlocal value
    value = True

value = [False]
def method_1_nonlocal_P2():
    value[0] = True
```

Comment: Note that with `global` it's not part of the closure any more and it can be messed up elsewhere in the program.

Comment: @agf -- quite so; I'm just trying to explain the scoping rules in as general a way as possible.

Answer (score 2):

When you assign to a variable, it assumes the variable is of local scope. So the `value` in `method_1` is not the `value` in `closure`.

If you want this to work on Python 3, add a line to `method_1`: `nonlocal value`.

On Python 2,

```
def closure():
    value = [False]

    def method_1():
        value[0] = True

    def method_2():
        print 'value is:', value

    method_1()
    method_2()

closure()
```

is one possible work-around.

Answer (score 2):

This is because you are not actually modified the closed-over variable - you are masking it with a new one that has the same name.  In python 2.x there is no easy way around this, which is why the `nonlocal` keyword was added in python 3.

This can be worked around, however, using mutable types like list and dictionary.  There is a [good example in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3190706/nonlocal-keyword-in-python-2-x).

Answer (score 1):

To avoid this, you can use a list.

```
value = [False]

def method_1():
    value[0] = True
```

What Python does now is searching in higher levels of the scope as *value* is not available in the local variables. As *value* is a list and Python refernces it as a global variable relative to *method_1*, you can treat *value* as it is, a list.