# Argument passing in Python

Tags: python

I don't quite understand what is going with variable 'current_label', which to me seems to be defined in the enclosing code of function 'ts_r', which would make it visible from inside 'ts_r'? But when I run the code below, it complains that local variable 'current_label' is referenced before assignment... Note that it does *not* complain about 'visited' or 'f', and that it won't complain if I initialize 'current_label' with [len(g)].

```
def topological_sort(g):

    visited = zeros((len(g)), dtype='int32')
    f = zeros((len(g)), dtype='int32')
    current_label = len(g) # [] so it is seen inside ts_r

    def ts_r(n):
        for nn in [v for v in g[n] if not visited[v]]:
            visited[nn] = 1
            ts_r(nn)
        f[n] = current_label
        current_label -= 1

    for i in range(len(g)):
        if not visited[i]: 
            ts_r(i)

    return f
```

Comment: Shame on whomever wrote obfuscated variable and method names in Python!

Comment: I tried to fix your indents but I realized its still odd. Can you please fix this formatting?

Comment: Done. Should look better now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case of `visited` or `f` **you change mutable variables**. In case of `current_label` you try to re-assign value to global variable without stating it is global.

Changing variables from outside scopes does not require declaring them global, but reassigning value to a global variable requires declaration, that it is global - otherwise it is treated as local (and in case of referencing before assignement you get such errors).

Lets look at the code:

```
1.    def ts_r(n):
2.        for nn in [v for v in g[n] if not visited[v]]:
3.            visited[nn] = 1
4.            ts_r(nn)
5.        f[n] = current_label
6.        current_label -= 1
```

In line `5` you assign global variable value to `f[n]`, but later, in line `6` you try to assign this global variable a value. You did not tell Python it is global, thus it assumes it is local. But if it is local, you cannnot assign it earlier.

You have two choices:

1. (probably not the one you are looking for) Use it as local:

   ```
   def ts_r(n):
       current_label = len(g)  # initialize local variable
       for nn in [v for v in g[n] if not visited[v]]:
           visited[nn] = 1
           ts_r(nn)
       f[n] = current_label
       current_label -= 1
   ```
2. Tell Python it is global variable and you would like to change global variable's value:

   ```
   def ts_r(n):
       global current_label  # current_label is now global
       for nn in [v for v in g[n] if not visited[v]]:
           visited[nn] = 1
           ts_r(nn)
       f[n] = current_label
       current_label -= 1
   ```

**EDIT**:

After your question was updated, I saw nested functions instead of functions defined in global scope. Thus the solution with `global` won't work.

In Python 3.x you have `nonlocal` keyword, but you will need to find walkaround in case of Python 2.x. Again, you have at least two possibilities:

1. Use mutable variable enclosing immutable you want to change (eg. list with one integer in it). Then when you just refer to (and change) the first element of a list. Try it.
2. Another solution is to add an attribute for the wrapping function (function is also a mutable, so you can change it, but you will not pollute global namespace). Example is here: http://ideone.com/7jGvM. In your case it may look like this:

   ```
   def topological_sort(g):

       visited = zeros((len(g)), dtype='int32')
       f = zeros((len(g)), dtype='int32')
       topological_sort.current_label = len(g) # [] so it is seen inside ts_r

       def ts_r(n):
           for nn in [v for v in g[n] if not visited[v]]:
               visited[nn] = 1
               ts_r(nn)
           f[n] = topological_sort.current_label
           topological_sort.current_label -= 1

       for i in range(len(g)):
           if not visited[i]: 
               ts_r(i)

       return f
   ```

Comment: Do you think its even necessary to have a local closure function in this situation in the first place?

Comment: @jdl: If you are referring to `ts_r`, then I do not have enough information. Maybe it is. Lets try to explain the error to OP.

Comment: Hmmmm... First, nothing in the syntax hints at current_label being of a different kind than f at the point of declaration. Why is current_label not considered a mutable variable too? - Second, if I don't want to pollute the global namespace, can I keep current_label's scope to be the whole of topological_sort, but not outside of it?

Comment: @Frank: type `int` is immutable. You keep reassigning it, as opposed to the others which are lists which you are only modifying by index. They stay the same object

Comment: Got it. I'll have to remember that type int is immutable. Remains the question about keeping current_label from spreading into the global namespace. By the way, I have to put a global declaration in topological_sort and another one in ts_r for the "global" thing to work.

Comment: @Frank: This is more in the way language works. Mutable are for example lists and dictionaries, but integers are not. I have just spotted (after someone has edited your question), that you have nested functions. In that case you can walk around this issue using this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3190783/548696. Newer versions of Python (3+) have `nonlocal` statements, that allow you to do that without polluting global namespace.

Comment: @Tadeck: That was what I was referring to, when I suggested the local closure wasn't even necc, because it was just nested and called in a loop.

Comment: OK, I also discovered that I can use a [] instead of dictionary, putting current_label in []. It works and Python doesn't complain.

Comment: @jdi: the nested function is because I don't want to expose it outside topological sort, but I really need, because it does a recursive call.

Comment: @Frank: Gah sorry. My eyes didn't zero in on the recursive call. You are right. But, about the [int] thing...that really just feels like a bandaid approach as opposed to structuring it better.  You will have to add the extra index lookup to each operation, instead of just decrementing a counter

Comment: @Tadeck: I like the solution to prefix with the name of the function. That's more "intuitive" than putting current_label in a dictionary or list, IMHO. Good stuff.