# Is there a way to detect if the user last entered text, or the program, in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, detect

This may be impossible, but (without making a variable be set after the computer prints something) know if the computer has printed something last, or the user. e.g.

```
answer = raw_input("Say something.")
if "ok" in answer.lower():
    print "Yay!"
if "poo" in answer.lower():
    print "That's very childish"
if (computer hasn't printed anything already):
    print "I'm not very talkative."
```

I have a lot of if branches to process the users input, but so loads of elifs and an else won't work. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you already mentioned, you *could* just set a variable, but that doesn't look nice.

Alternatively you could collect your output:

```
answer = raw_input("Say something.")
output = []
if "ok" in answer.lower():
    output.append("Yay!")
if "poo" in answer.lower():
    output.append("That's very childish")
if not output:
    output.append("I'm not very talkative.")
for o in output:
  print o
```

Disclaimer: I don't do much Python coding, so I have no idea if that's pythonic enough.

Comment: I have already made all the print statements... This would take just as long, though is a interesting idea

Comment: Nothing that a little search-and-replace (with the regex-supporting editor of your choice) can't fix: `s/print \(.*\)/output.append(\1)/` ;-)

Comment: Yes though I still have to insert the )s afterwards and I have lots of prints all around the place.

Answer (score 0):

You also define a inner function to handle the printing and setting of the variable:

```
def handler(answer):
  handler.responded = False
  def respond(output):
    handler.responded = True
    print output
  if "ok" in answer:
    respond("Yay!")
  if not handler.responded:
    respond("I'm not very talkative")
```

This uses the "nonlocal"-replacement as discussed [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3190706/nonlocal-keyword-in-python-2-x).

If you could use Python 3, this code could be a bit nicer by using `nonlocal`:

```
def handler(answer):
  responded = False
  def respond(output):
    nonlocal responded
    responded = True
    print(output)
  if "ok" in answer:
    respond("Yay!")
  if not responded:
    respond("I'm not very talkative")
```

Comment: This would include writing all my code into a function, and replacing all the prints with responds. Another good idea, but I'm looking for if there's a value already stored in python to tell me really.