# Python UnboundLocalError Embedded def

Tags: python

This usually works; however, it's not this time:

```
def fn(text):
    def fn2():
        print text

    fn2()
```

How can I fix this?

Thanks.

Edit: I don't want to pass in text.

Comment: Works just fine for me.

Comment: Could you post the full stack trace?  It works for me too.

Comment: Maybe a solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3190706/nonlocal-keyword-in-python-2-x

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest reading this page: http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/05/15/understanding-unboundlocalerror-in-python/

So where does the exception come from? Quoting the FAQ:

This is because when you make an assignment to a variable in a scope, that variable becomes local to that scope and shadows any similarly named variable in the outer scope.

Comment: the posted code _works_, so presumably it's not what's actually being run.