# Accessing function-local variable

Tags: python, function, undefined, local-variables

This code

```
def reportRealDiagnostics():

        ranks = 0
        class Rank: 
            def __init__(self):
                global ranks
                ranks += 1
        rank = Rank()

reportRealDiagnostics()
```

produces

```
NameError: global name 'ranks' is not defined
```

I am sure that this is all what you need to answer the question.

Comment: "I am sure that this is all what you need to answer the question." It would have been better to **ask a question**, starting with a question word like "why" or "how", and ending with a question mark (`?`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use `global ranks` it looks for `ranks` in the global scope not in enclosing scope, so you get that error. The `ranks` you've defined is part of the enclosing scope.

In Python3 this has been resolved and you can modify `ranks` by using the `nonlocal` keyword:

```
def reportRealDiagnostics():
        ranks = 0
        class Rank: 
            def __init__(self):
                nonlocal ranks
                ranks += 1
        rank = Rank()

reportRealDiagnostics()
```

In Python2 you can define it as a function attribute:

```
def reportRealDiagnostics():
        class Rank: 
            def __init__(self):
                reportRealDiagnostics.ranks += 1
        rank = Rank()
reportRealDiagnostics.ranks = 0
reportRealDiagnostics()
```

---

There are some other alternatives too: [`nonlocal` keyword in Python 2.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3190706/nonlocal-keyword-in-python-2-x)

Comment: It is important to remember that the second option is not semantically the same.  It puts `ranks` in the global scope, it is just hidden in the function's namespace.  Multiple invocations of reportRealDiagnostics will use the same variable.  It still might be OK.

Comment: There is a more serious problem than just global scope with python 2.x. The problem is that **you must initialize the function-local variables every time before you call the function.** This defeats the whole idea of having local variables.

Comment: @Val If you're talking about [this](http://docs.python.org/2/faq/programming.html#why-am-i-getting-an-unboundlocalerror-when-the-variable-has-a-value), then this is not a issue related to py2.x, it works similarly in py3.x as as well. I wouldn't call it a issue as well.

Comment: Wait, you say that option is intended for Python2. Who cares about it regarding Py3?

Comment: My point was that you better declare a global variable as per normal rather than do it and initialize it properly at every call of you function. The point (of the very function) is that you initialize the `ranks` variable to a proper value in the parent function. Caller should not do that. He better not beware that such variable even exists. I have checked that you can declare the variable easily by simply defined in global `reportRealDiagnostics` function. You should have `def f(): global r; r = 1; class C: __init__ global r; access(r)`

Comment: @Val Using `globals` like that is usually not recommended, better use a `Class`. Plus when you import your function to some other module then `global r` in `f()` is still going to point to the global namespace in original file, it won't create or access a global in the current module.

Answer (score 0):

You should use variable as nonlocal:

```
nonlocal ranks
```