# How to declare a variable is from the enclosing scope?

Tags: python, python-2.7

How do I make code like the following work? I want to reference a variable, for assignment, in the enclosing function scope.

```
def outer():
    x = 0

    def inner():
        x += 1

    inner()
```

The code as written gives an `UnboundLocalError`. I understand why I get this error, I just don't know how I indicate that `x` comes from the wrapping scope.

Comment: You can't re-bind (assign) to variables in non-local/non-global scopes.

Comment: I suppose I need Python 3's `nonlocal` keyword.

Comment: Possibly a duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3190706/nonlocal-keyword-in-python-2-x

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do what you ask in a clean way. There is nothing analagous to the `global` statement that can help you. You'll want to code it like this:

```
def outer():
    x = 0

    def inner(x):
        return x + 1

    x = inner(x)
```

This has the added advantage of making it explicitly clear as to how data passes into, and out of, the function.

Perhaps you will need to replace `x` with an object whose state can be mutated.

Comment: If it were a simple function I'd do this, but it's more of a state update function that modifies several items and does other operations.

Comment: I'm afraid that your desires don't change what the language has to offer.

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
def outer():
    x = [0]

    def inner():
        x[0] += 1

    inner()
```

You can't rebind a non-local, but you can mutate it.