# Python closure confusion

Tags: python, closures

I was playing around with closures in Python and I do not understand why the following does not work and how to make it work:

```
>>> def make_counter():
...     i = 0
...     def inner():
...         i += 1
...         return i
...     return inner
...
>>> c = make_counter()
>>> c()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in inner
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'i' referenced before assignment
```

Could anybody shed some light on it?
Thanks.

Comment: In this particular case, you are better off using `c = itertools.count()`. Then use `foo = next(c)` to increment the count

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the `inner` function, the statement

```
i += 1
```

can be understood like this

```
i = i + 1
```

since you are assigning a value to `i` in this function, Python thinks that you are creating a new variable scoped to this current function. And then when it executes the right hand side expression, `i + 1`, it finds that `i` has not been assigned any value before using it. That is why it is throwing

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'i' referenced before assignment
```

To fix this, you need to explicitly tell Python that you are not creating a new variable, instead, you are accessing a variable from the outer scope, with [`nonlocal`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-nonlocal-statement) (Python 3.x) like this

```
>>> def make_counter():
...     i = 0
...     def inner():
...         nonlocal i
...         i += 1
...         return i
...     return inner
... 
>>> 
>>> make_counter()()
1
```

**Note:** If you are using Python 2.x, follow any of the methods mentioned in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3190706/1903116)