# python closure/nested function fail when with assignment to outer array

Tags: python, closures

It seems that the closure of a python function has problems if the symbol
referenced is assigned:

```
def outer():
    p = []
    def gen():
        def touch(e):
            if e[0] == 'add':
                p.append(e);
            elif e[0] == 'rem':
                p = [ x for x in p if not (x[1] == e[1]) ]
        return touch
    f = gen()
    for i in [["add","test1"],["add","test2"],["rem","test2"],["rem","test1"]]:
        f(i)      

outer();
```

and the result is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "b.py", line 22, in <module>
    outer();
  File "b.py", line 20, in outer
    f(i)      
  File "b.py", line 14, in touch
    p.append(e);
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'p' referenced before assignment
```

If I just for test replace:

```
 -       p = [ x for x in p if not (x[1] == e[1]logig is) ]                                                                                                                                
 +       a = [ x for x in p if not (x[1] == e[1]) ]
```

the error dissapears, however the code is not what I want. Is the above behaviour expected with python closures/nested functions? Do I need to wrap the array to modify inside a object and just call functions?

On the other hand this one works:

```
class o():
    def __init__(self):
        self.p = []
    def add(self,e):
        self.p.append(e);
    def rem(self,e):
        self.p = [ x for x in self.p if not (x[1] == e[1]) ]

def outer():
    p = o()
    def gen():
        def touch(e):
            if e[0] == 'add':
                p.add(e);
            elif e[0] == 'rem':
                p.rem(e)
        return touch
    f = gen()
    for i in [["add","test1"],["add","test2"],["rem","test2"],["rem","test1"]]:
        f(i)      

outer();
```

Comment: It seems to work fine if you define p in the touch function

Comment: That is not a closure. https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/closure

Comment: Or else you can define `def touch(e, p):` and call using `touch(i, p)`

Comment: @Alexander : You where right, I changed the title / example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are assigning `p` inside `touch`, it becomes a local variable in `touch` and effectively "hides" all other names `p` in enclosing scopes.  In order to tell Python that you actually want to refer to the `p` within `outer`, you should use `nonlocal p`, for example:

```
def outer():
    p = []
    def touch(e):
        # The following line is required to refer to outer's p
        nonlocal p
        if e[0] == 'add':
            p.append(e)
        elif e[0] == 'rem':
            p = [ x for x in p if not (x[1] == e[1]) ]
    for i in [["add","test1"],["add","test2"],["rem","test2"],["rem","test1"]]:
        touch(i)
outer()
```

Your second example works because you are referring to an attribute of `p` in both cases of `touch`, rather than making an assignment (`p = ...`).

See [`nonlocal` in the Python reference documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#nonlocal), the reference documentation for [scopes](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/executionmodel.html#resolution-of-names), and [PEP 3104](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3104/) in which the `nonlocal` syntax was proposed.  `nonlocal` only exists in Python 3, but [there is a workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3190706/nonlocal-keyword-in-python-2-x) if it is necessary to use Python 2.

Comment: Quite nasty pitfall. Thanks for the tip.