# Error in the python script

Tags: python

I have this simple python script where `myvar1` is accessible in `generate()` function but not in `copy()` function. Need help figuring out the error:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import os, time

def Test(tcid,descr,iterations,filsz):

        def setup():
                print "entering set up\n"
                global myvar1, myvar2

                myvar1 = 1.0
                myvar2 = os.getcwd()

        def generate():
                print "entering generate\n"
                print "in generate", myvar1, myvar2

        def copy():

           print "in copy", myvar1, myvar2
           myvar1 += 5.0



        setup()
        generate()

        for loopcount in range(5):
           loopcount = loopcount + 1
           copy()



if __name__ == "__main__":
        Test('test','simple test',2,10)
```

Error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./pyerror.py", line 35, in 
    Test('test','simple test',2,10)
  File "./pyerror.py", line 30, in Test
    copy()
  File "./pyerror.py", line 20, in copy
    print "in copy", myvar1, myvar2
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'myvar1' referenced before assignment

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python scope problems only when _assigning_ to a variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2886932/python-scope-problems-only-when-assigning-to-a-variable)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `global` wherever you overwrite a global in a function. `setup` set `myvar1` as a global but you used it as a unset local variable. Hence the "local variable 'myvar1' referenced before assignment"

```
def copy():
    global myvar1
    print "in copy", myvar1, myvar2
    myvar1 += 5.0
```

If you're reading a tutorial that suggests using `global` regularly then throw it away, burn it and start with a different one.

Answer (score 2):

In the `copy()` function, `myvar1` is not declared as global, but assigned to in the statement `myvar1 += 5.0`.  This implicitly makes the `myvar1` a local variable.  The print statement in the first line of the function also tries to access a local variable with the name `myvar1`, but such a local variable does not exist yet.

Local variables are determined statically, i.e. at compile time.  When the `copy()` is compiled by Python, `myvar1` is marked as local variable for the whole function body.  It may be instructive to look at the easiest code to trigger this error:

```
def f():
    print x
    x = 5
x = 3
f()
```